# Read line by line through a fifo

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm an absolute beginner with Unix programming, I've to make a program that reads from the standard input some commands and then another program that execute those commands. I've to use a fifo in order to establish a communication between those two program. 
My problem is: how can I make possible reading line by line (one command) from a fifo where those line doesn't have a fixed size ? I was thinking to implement with signal a sort of synchronization, however I'm sure there are better ways.

I'm sorry if it's a banal question, but I'm a perfect newbie with this things.

Oh and sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: I've actually started learning IPC and I've already made something involving the exchange of continuous stream or fixed size elements. My main problem here is to managed distinct strings with not fixed lengths. However I'm currently trying to increase my knowledge, but I've very demanding deadlines, that's why I've asked for some help.

Comment: code is more expressive then language. if you have tried something, post a snippet of it, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Now, sadly, I'm not with my computer. However I've nothing on this particular problem because I've  no idea on how solve it at the moment. All my other stuff on IPC (nothing more of what I've told you up there) are actually working. However tomorrow I'll try something and post it here!

Comment: `man realloc`.  Allocate a fixed size buffer and read data into it.  If you get to the end of the buffer before you get to the end of the line, make the buffer larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you were reading with `read()`?  Just use `fgets()` and let the stdlib handle the buffering.  If you used `open()` rather than `fopen()` then get your FILE structure with `fdopen()` first.  Something like:

```
FILE * pFile;

char mystring [100];

pFile = fopen("myfifo" , "r");

if (pFile == NULL)
{   perror ("Error opening fifo");
    exit(1);
}

while (fgets(mystring, 100, pFile) != NULL)
    puts(mystring);

fclose (pFile);
```

Comment: That's cool thank you, however if I have to use syscalls (I mean directly, with read/open/write etc.)?  I was thinking to read a continuous stream char by char and as soon as I read a '\0' put those char apart as a string ? However thank you so much,I'll ask if I'm allowed to use those function